# Error in printing all substrings of a string

Tags: c++, string, substring

This is in reference to the following answer by Synxis.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18684/find-all-substrings-interview-query-in-c/18715#18715

Suppose, I have to print all substrings of the string "cbaa". To do this, I have to invoke the method like this:

```
findAllSubstrings2("cbaa");
```

If I take a string from user, and do the following:

```
string s;
cin>>s;
findAllSubstrings2(s);
```

it gives the following error:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'void findAllSubstrings2(const char*)'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You are using `string` and the function accepts an array of `char`. Change  your `string s` to `char[] s`.

Comment: But when I type findAllSubstrings2("cbaa"), I have passed a string argument and the function works correct for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says the parameter of function `findAllSubstrings2` is declared as having type `const char *` while you are trying to pass an argument of type `std::string`

```
string s;
//...
findAllSubstrings2(s);
```

You should use member function `c_str` or `data` (starting from C++ 11) of class `std::string`. For example

```
findAllSubstrings2(s.c_str());
```

Comment: s.c_str() worked. But can you tell me why findAllSubstrings2("cbaa") worked?

Comment: @Shubham Bhattar String literals have types of constant character arrays in C++. When they are passed by value as in your example to a function they are converted to pointers to their first characters and have the type const char *. So there is no problem of calling your function with a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

you using string, in function is char try to use char[] s;

Comment: Yes, I tried converting the string to character array and it worked. But my concern is when I explicitly pass a string argument, its working and when i pass a string variable it gives error.

Comment: just use in `function findAllSubstrings2(s.c_str()); ` then

Answer (score 1):

use [c_str() method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) in string class when passing the argument

```
string s;
cin>>s;
findAllSubstrings2(s.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should change the type of the parameter of the function. Somethink like:

```
void findAllSubstrings2(string s){
 //... function implementation...
}
```